# Calculate probability of overlapping collections of marked balls

Tags: probability

I am working on a side project of my own entertainment and being a mathematician I of course had to start generalizing it. Not that I managed to solve it for even one case because probability is my weakest point. Anyway I will reframe the problem into classical balls and collections.

We have marked balls, from $1$ to $m$, in many copies. Out of these we create collections with no duplicates, so there can only be 1 ball of a specific marking in a collection, ranging in size from $n>4$ to $N< m$. The $4$ is because we assume that every collection contains balls $1$ through $4$ and it is all $>4$ that are randomly picked with a uniform distribution so the total count is $n\leq a \leq N$. Now, assume we have a collection $C$ of these balls, how do we calculate the probability that a randomly selected collection $C_r$ has $s>4$ balls in common with $C$?

I have had ideas of various sorts on how to solve this but quite frankly, I get boggled down with the possibilities as this is really my weakest point in mathematics. So anyone have an idea how to calculate this or is it uncalculable?

Comment: It is an interesting question but you need to specify more precisely how the randomly selected collection $C_r$ is selected. I see two possibilities that are consistent with your post. 1) We first create all possible collections that satisfy the constraints in the post. Then we select one of them where all collections have equal probability. 2) We first select $a$ from the uniform distribution on $[n, N]$, then create all collections with $a$ elements containing the balls 1 through 4 and then pick one of *these* collections with equal probability.

Comment: It is maybe not obvious that the two methods are different but they are. Say $m = 20$. Then there are much more collections with 12 balls (12870) than there are with 5 balls (20). In scenario 1, $C_r$ hence has bigger probability of having 12 balls than having 5 balls, in scenario 2 these probabilities are equal. Conversely, suppose that $C$ has 5 balls. Then the probability that the random collection $C_r$ actually equals $C$ (which is not the probability you are after, but still relevant) is bigger in scenario 2 than it is in scenario 1